# hbase command versus hadoop command

Tags: hadoop, hbase

The little bit of description of hbase in the O'Reilly Elephant book shows the use of the 'hbase' command line wrapper to run a map-reduce job using hbase.

However, our code has a long classpath, so we want to use the lib directory feature of hadoop enabled by JobConf.setClassByJar and the 'hadoop' command. While we may have messed something up, it seemed to us that this did not work with the hbase command.

Can ordinary hadoop jobs call the hbase API? Just what does the hbase command-line do?

(hadoop 0.20.2, hbase corresponding)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HBase API in a Hadoop job.

Here are some code snippets for using HBase API in a Job.

Imports

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
```

This is inside a `@Override` function in my code

```
private HTable hTable = null;
Configuration hConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hConfig.set(Constants.HBASE_CONFIGURATION_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, zkQuorum);
hConfig.set(Constants.HBASE_CONFIGURATION_ZOOKEEPER_CLIENTPORT, zkclientPort);
hTable = new HTable(hConfig, hbCube);
...
hTable.put(subPuts);
```

Obviously not complete snippets, but with the right `imports` and providing the correct values your job (I only had a mapper) can access the HBase API.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. How we do it is, package everything (including the HBase jar) in a fat jar and run the Hadoop command.

The hbase command line utility can be used for:

1. Tables access - this lets you scan your tables, run compactions, enable/disable tables, etc.It is like any other database shell, but more powerful because as in my next point
2. You can run jruby scripts with the command:

   ```
   hbase org.jruby.Main <your_script>
   ```
3. You can even run your Java stuff while you are in the shell. This can be helpful for printing out cluster properties, etc.
   examples here:
   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell